# Eloquent - Multiple belongsTo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I can't seem to find a straight answer on whether Eloquent models can have multiple belongsTo relationships.

Just in terms of normalized DB relationships, this is perfectly valid. Let's take the hypothetical example of a CMS page that belongs to one and only one author, and also belongs to one and only one category. The author and category have no relation to or bearing on one another. In the DB, we'd simply expect a page to have an author_id and a category_id field, each with a foreign key to a different table.

Seems like it would be valid to do:

```
class Page extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

The scenario seems valid ... EXCEPT that this seems to break the convention and automagic of the `associate` and `dissociate` methods, which expect there to be only a single "belongs to" relationship.

So is it proper to use multiple `belongsTo` relationships on the same model? And if not, how would you express a common scenario like this instead?  (I should note right off the bat that this is not the same scenario as polymorphic relationships, where one model belongs to one other, which may be this OR that type.)

Comment: you mean a Belongs To Many relationships?

Comment: No, belongsToMany is used to define many to many relationships, which requires a linking table.  This is a question about TWO different one to many relationships.

Comment: what about these TWO different belongs to relationships? what about them? ... also what do you mean "which expects there to be only a single "belongs to" relationship? ... you could have as many belongsTo relationships as you have foreign keys on the table, there is no limit

Comment: "you could have as many belongsTo relationships as you have foreign keys on the table, there is no limit"

Well, that answers my primary question, if you CAN do it.

However, what about the `associate` method?  Are you familiar with it? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships  What would `associate` do when there are multiple belongsTo relationships?

Comment: `associate` and `dissociate` are called on the Relationships not the Model itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent Model's can have multiple same relationship. Means you can have `belongsToMany()` as many as you need, you can have a `belongsTo()`, `hasOne()`, `hasMany()` etc. It will not affect the other relationship since they have a different method name. which is the main identification for the relationship.

> The scenario seems valid ... EXCEPT that this seems to break the convention and automagic of the associate and dissociate methods, which expect there to be only a single "belongs to" relationship.

If you understand the documentation [Updating BelongsTo Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) you will use the `associate()` or `dissociate()` after the relationship method. There's no `"except there to be only a single belongs to relationship".` in the documentation.

```
$page->author()->dissociate(); // it will set the "author_id" on the page as null and will not affect the `category()` at all.

$page->category()->associate($category); // it will add a the "category_id" of the given category to the page and will not affect the `author()` at all.
```

Comment: D'oh.  I was reading the documentation as the method being called directly on the model.  Whelp, much ado over nothing then!  Thanks!